# Azure Pipeline passing argument along with docker build doesn't work

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I am building an Azure pipeline, that create a docker image. During this docker image creation I need to create an environment variable that will be used in the application later on. However when I run this in Azure pipeline it doesn't pass the argument to docker file.

But I tried running docker build locally with the same argument, it passed the argument correctly.

Azure pipeline task:

```
- task: Docker@2
        displayName: Build and Push
        inputs:
          command: buildAndPush
          repository: ${{ variables.repository }}
          dockerfile: ${{ variables.dockerfile }}
          arguments: '--build-arg ASHTESTARG=1234 .'
          tags: latest
```

Docker file:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

# Define the build argument
ARG ASHTESTARG

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /mockbin

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --only=production
COPY . .

# Set the environment variables
ENV ASHDEBUGENV $ASHTESTARG
RUN echo "My Test $ASHDEBUGENV"

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When running in the pipeline it does not set the variable.
[image]

But if I build the image locally with below command, it works.

```
docker build -t mockbinashtest:latest --build-arg ASHTESTARG=1111 .
```

[image]

Any idea why this is not working in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is, Docker@2 buildAndPush command does not support arguments. I need to break this task into two separate tasks.

```
- task: Docker@2
        displayName: Build Docker Image
        inputs:
          command: build
          repository: ${{ variables.repository }}
          dockerfile: ${{ variables.dockerfile }}
          buildContext: .
          arguments: '--build-arg ASHTESTARG=1234'
          tags: latest
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Push Docker Image
        inputs:
          command: push
          repository: ${{ variables.repository }}
          tags: latest
```